# UPDATE column for a large table with a single value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, sql-update

I have a table with **2 billion** rows.
The recovery mode is simple.

I have a simple task to do:

```
UPDATE myTable SET columnA = 'X'
```

The task seems easy at first, but everywhere I read that it is better to make a SELECT INTO another table, or do a batch update.

Is a batch update neccesary ? Will the query above blow up the transaction log ?

If I create another table I will for sure run out of space.

**Any** help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I do not have a primary key. Also, no indexes, no constraints, anything.

Perhaps this would help ?

```
SET rowcount 10000
Update myTable 
set columnA ='X'
where columnA <> 'X'

while @@rowcount>0

BEGIN
SET rowcount 10000
Update myTable 
set columnA ='X'
where columnA <> 'X'

end

SET rowcount 0
```

Comment: Don't forget to set your database to simple recovery when doing this. Obviously, you'll want to back it up first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty wild and `non-sql` way but you can use `ETL` tools(such as `SSIS`) to avoid logging to a large extent.

Disclaimer: It can be a time consuming step and may take up file space on your server.

Have two data flow tasks(DFT1, DFT2).

**DFT1**

[image]

Using Derived Column transformation, pass the value "A" instead of the actual value of `columnA`.

The flat file now will have the requisite data. Next step would be to import this onto the table.

*Outside the DFT*, truncate this table now. `TRUNCATE` as you probably know is non-logged operation. So your transaction log won't be touched.

And then finally,

**DFT2**

Import the data onto tableA from the flat file.

[image]

`SSIS` internally does minimal logging, so again the trasaction log won't be bothered too much.

Also, I just saw you have added the ssis tag in your question, so this answer should be valid then.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in batches

```
 Declare @pk integer = 0
 declare @max integer
 select @max = Max(primKeyCol) from myTable
 While @pk < @Max Begin
      Update myTable set columnA = 'X'
      Where primKeyCol Between @pk and @pk + 999
      Set @pk += 1000
 End
```

Comment: I do not have a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a batch update because this kind of UPDATE in a big table can cause a lot of locks.
I found a good example of the batches [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15977.sql-server-batch-update.aspx)

Comment: Could you please explain the query ?

For me, it looks like it would update the first 1000 rows continually.

Thank you.

Comment: In your case, you can add WHERE clause to your UPDATE and get the records that columnA is not 'X' - So it will execute the statement for the rows that haven't being updated before.

Comment: Ok, that would make it work.

Though, the table is not in use by any other resource. 
Would that make the batch update pointless ?

Comment: I would still use the batch update in order to prevent a long transaction and be in a risk of getting rollback for the whole transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating 50.000 rows at a time

```
DECLARE @chk INT = 1
WHILE @chk > 0
BEGIN
  ;WITH CTE as
  (
    SELECT TOP 50000 columnA
    FROM myTable
    -- the reason for this check is to check for NULLS in columnA
    -- otherwise it could just be columnA <> 'X'
    WHERE exists(SELECT columnA EXCEPT SELECT 'X')
  )
  UPDATE CTE SET columnA = 'X'
  SET @chk = @@rowcount
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30' -- 30 seconds, may need to change it
END
```

From microsoft [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SET_ROWCOUNT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

> Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE
>   statements in a future release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT
>   with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work,
>   and plan to modify applications that currently use it. For a similar
>   behavior, use the TOP syntax. For more information, see TOP
>   (Transact-SQL).

Comment: Hello, Is this recursive ? It looks like a one time 50000 row update.
Thank you.

Comment: @DragosDurlut it is in a loop now, a delay has been added

Comment: Why the `WAITFOR DELAY`?

Comment: because when i did a similar script and didn't have breaks, the transaction log ran full. I hoped this would fix it